# How to compare two sets of time-series 3-Dimensional data?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, manova, paired-comparisons

Let us say we have two data sets. Each of the data sets has velocity $(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ and acceleration $(a_x,a_y,a_z)$ of particles at time steps n where $0 \leq n \leq 100,000$. Now how do I compare these two sets of data ? What statistical techniques can I use? What can be inferred by application of those statistical techniques?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the KS-test , so you can determine if the two data sets came from the same distribution or not.

> The two-sample K–S test is one of the most useful and general
>   nonparametric methods for comparing two samples, as it is sensitive to
>   differences in both location and shape of the empirical cumulative
>   distribution functions of the two samples.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

Comment: It is difficult to see how this would be relevant to *time series* with *six values,* given that the KS test concerns *independent* samples with *one value* per observation.